# Ограничение количества символов в инпуте

Tags: html, reactjs, input, валидация

Есть переиспользуемый инпут(компонент)

```
<Input/>
```

Как ограничить введенное количество символов в инпут?
Чтобы работало как maxlength = "14"
Но тут это св-во не работает, т,к это компонент

Comment: Инпут используется в react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { form: { message: "" } };

  handleChangeInput = event => {
    const { value, maxLength } = event.target;
    const message = value.slice(0, maxLength);

    this.setState({
      form: {
        message
      }
    });
  };
  render(){
    return (
        <>
         <Input  changed={this.handleChangeInput} />
         <input
             onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
             value={this.state.form.message}
             type="text"
             maxLength="11"
              />
       </>
    )
  }
}
```

Отдельный Компонент

```
<Input  changed={this.handleChangeInput} />
```

Компонент **Input**

```
export default props => {
  return (
    <input onChange={props.changed}/> 
  )
}
```

Comment: а если нет доступа к компоненту? т.е он находится в node modules

Comment: @Aaaa это какой то пакет?Если да то посмотрите в доках этого пакета .Если нету там инфы насчет этого то надо будет уже вам переписать этот компонент по другому никак .